# How to track mouse X/Y position and print it to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, mousemove, low-level-api

I know how to modify cursor position from examples on MSDN.

My question is how to check position of mouse while mouse moves and then print X and Y position to representing labels?

EDIT: Lets say I want to track my mouse position from my entire screen.

EDIT 2: My app will be in the back ground/minimized.

I'm already using Mouse Hooks:

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class MouseHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        public void DoMouseClick()
        {
            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

            IntPtr newP = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64("0", 16));
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, newP);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been asked many times already.  Type "+setwindowshookex +wh_mouse_ll" in the search box.  Or just use a 50 msec Timer and Cursor.Position

Comment: @Hans Passant, Timer solution seems to be the simplest for checking the x/y position. I just need to figure out how to check the position now. +1 for this :)

Comment: @Cody Gray, how is this question a duplicate if question was posted 3 years before noted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the msdn documentation on system level mouse event handling calls (low level mouse proc).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182813/cant-send-new-scroll-direction-with-sendinput-in-lowlevelmouseproc-call) is an example of using low level mouse procs to change the scroll event.

In the answer in the second link use WM_MOUSEMOVE from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of WM_MOUSEWHEEL.

One thing to note: for this program to continue to capture mouse events when the mouse is over a program with elevated privileges, this program will have to be launch with elevated privileges.

Code (not tested):

```
using System;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CatchMouseMove
{
    class InterceptMouse
    {
        const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
        const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14; 


        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public static void Main()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

            if (_hookID == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SetWindowsHookEx Failed");
                return;
            }
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            int xPos = 0;
            int yPos = 0;

            if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {    
                xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
                yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

                //do stuff with xPos and yPos
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }


        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public int mouseData;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        public struct INPUT
        {
            public int type;
            public MOUSEINPUT mi;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public int mouseData;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }



        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a Windows hook in order to achieve this. The MSDN article [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804/en-us) shows how to set a mouse hook.

I tried it, it captures the mouse all over the form, even when the mouse cursor is over a control.

Comment: This example is good except it is setup for an independent thread that finds your form rather than being directly tied to the form.

Comment: Yes, but it is easy to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the EventArgs of the [MouseMove event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx), because it holds the mouse coordinates. From there you can easily set the text property of the label to the X or Y coordinate you will take from `e` (the MouseMove EventArgs).

```
private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the mouse coordinates displayed in the textbox.
    myTextBox.Text = e.Location.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I get the idea. But since I must have an object to do the handler to for example: `textBox1.TextChanged += new EventArgs(textBox1_TextChanged);` which object would I call?

Comment: @Help: `TextChanged` is the wrong event. You want to handle the `MouseMove` event. Inside of that event handler method, update your textbox: `textBox1.Text = e.Location.ToString();`

Comment: @Cody Gray, I do know. But my question is what object I would refer to, meaning what I would substitute textBox1 to?

Comment: @Help: Oh, probably your Form. The problem you'll run into is that whenever the cursor moves over a child control that is on top of the form, it won't raise the event on the form.

Comment: Do you really need to track mouse movements in the entire window, or just some control (like a pane, etc.)?

Comment: @Vladislav Zorov, I would prefer to track mouse over my entire screen.

Comment: Oh... that changes a lot.. I guess there should be some Windows API, but it gets more complicated. Games do it by opening a window exactly as big as the screen, which contains a single pane that receives events and gets drawn to.

Comment: @Vladislav Zorov, I'm sorry. I have updated my OP. Also I want to point out that I want my app to track the cursor while being in background.