# How would I update mouse position in ToolStripStatusLabel

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-position, toolstripstatuslabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to track mouse X/Y position and print it to a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871393/how-to-track-mouse-x-y-position-and-print-it-to-a-label)

I seem to have run into a road bump with what seems to be a small problem but can't seem to find the answer.
This is my first question asked here, and I apologize if I missed the solution to this question!

I have a toolStripStatusLabel that I want to have the current position of the mouse, I was able to get the coordinates doing this:

```
private void mouseCoordinatesToolStripStatusLabel()
{
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = MousePosition.ToString();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

But this has only been able to get me the mouse's position when I load and not when I move my mouse.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the mouse cursor coordinates:

```
...
this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString() + " - " + Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
...
```

If you want to be updated on mouse move, just bind the `MouseMove` event from your Form and add previous code. Actually, yours is ok too, you just seem to be missing to bind the the `MouseMove` event.

Comment: I was able to get the position with my current code, but I've honestly never used (or at least gotten a grip on) event handlers, would it be possible you could help me by showing me (or even linking me to) how to attach it to a MouseMove event handler?



'private void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = MousePosition.ToString();
            this.Refresh();
        }'

Comment: On your form class constructor write `this.MouseMove +=` then press "TAB" twice and it will attach a new method. Other common option is to set it on the designer, see the properties window, there's an **Events** botton where you can attach to events from your form, doble clicking them.

Comment: Handling the event through the property window was exactly what I needed, thank you! In case others see this, what I did was click on my pictureBox in the designer (I was aiming to watch the mouse movement there specifically), Event tab > Scrolled down to MouseMove > Attached it to my mouseMove functions > `private void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = MousePosition.ToString();
            this.Refresh();
        }`

And that worked out great, it adjusts to images loaded to it as well, but the coords are for the whole form.

Comment: Found a solution online and figured out the pictureBox problem just now and figured I should add it here too. My pictureBox1 is set to AutoSize and is in a panel and I'm loading an image through an openFileDialog. First I wrote `Point LocalMousePosition { get; set; }`, then changed the code in my mouseMove function to `private void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            LocalMousePosition = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = LocalMousePosition.ToString();
        }` and it now shows the mouse coords over the image!