# how to set mouse hook for another application in c#

Tags: c#

In my c# application, I want to set the mouse hook up for another application. While googling i found an example for mouse hook up but they are given for same application what i am working currently.Refer the link below,
[Mouse Hook up link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/318804) . Pls guide me to solve this issue

Comment: You need to ask something specific, else this will be flagged as too broad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871393/how-to-track-mouse-x-y-position-and-print-it-to-a-label

Answer (score 0):

> Mouse hook is useful for hook up the mouse events in same class alone . not for the outside application